# Magento 2 How can I add unit of the data in the ui form field?

Tags: magento2, price, currency, ui-form, custom-field

I need to indicate the user that the  “unit” of the data to be input, such as currency.

[image]

I am using ui component form. How can I achieve it?

Here is my code

```
<field name="total">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Amount</item>
             <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
             <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
             <item name="source" xsi:type="string">total</item>
             <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             </item>
         </item>
     </argument>
 </field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add **"addbefore"** attribute to your UI component form field.
Follow this code:

```
<field name="xxxxx"  sortOrder="50" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">xxxxx xxxxx</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">ordercombine</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">xxxxx</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="addbefore" xsi:type="string">$</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```